# Show $\ln(x)$ continuous at $x = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

For $\ln x $ to be continuous at $x = 1$ we need to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $ 0 < |x - 1| < \delta \implies |\ln x - \ln 1 | < \epsilon $. So for a given epsilon we have:

$ |\ln x - \ln 1| = | \ln x | < \epsilon \ . $

We have two cases: (1) $x \geq 1$ and (2) $x < 1$. For (1) we have $|x - 1| = x - 1$ and thus

$\ln x < \epsilon \iff x < e^\epsilon \iff x - 1 < e^\epsilon - 1 \iff |x-1| < e^\epsilon - 1 \ .$

There we can choose $\delta = e^\epsilon - 1$ whenever $x \geq 1 $. For (2) we have $|\ln x | = - \ln x $, $|x - 1| = -(x - 1)$ and thus

$- \ln x < \epsilon \iff x > \frac 1{\epsilon} \iff x - 1 > \frac 1{\epsilon} - 1 \iff -|x - 1| > \frac 1{\epsilon} - 1 \iff |x - 1| < 1 - \frac 1{ \epsilon } $

This time we can choose $\delta = 1 - \frac 1{\epsilon}$. But now we have two different deltas for different intervals, so what do we do in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you define $\log x$? For example, you can use $$\log x=\int_1^x t^{-1}dt$$ Then, it is immediate $\log x$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Is there no to way to do it the way I attempted to?

Comment: For (2), $-\ln x < \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow x>e^{-\epsilon} = \dfrac{1}{e^{-\epsilon}}$

Comment: Once you have found the 2 deltas (say $\delta_1$ for the first case and $\delta_2$ for the second) you can put $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and it will be useful for both cases.

Comment: To follow up on the previous 2 comments, you can let $\delta=\min\{e^{\epsilon}-1,1-e^{-\epsilon}\}$, which gives $\delta=1-e^{-\epsilon}$.